# Set datatype on END AS in CASE ELSE statement - PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to make INT be the data type for this column I'm creating. How do I do that? I tried adding AS INT to the end of END AS "salary_deviation" but that does not work. I tried wrapping END AS in CAST() but that didnt work either.

```
   CASE 
        WHEN c.salary = pair.salary THEN '6'
        
        WHEN c.salary-pair.salary <= 25000 THEN '5'
        
        WHEN c.salary-pair.salary <= 50000 THEN '4'
        
        WHEN c.salary-pair.salary <= 75000 THEN '3'

        WHEN c.salary-pair.salary <= 100000 THEN '2'
        
    ELSE
        '1'
    END AS "salary_deviation"
```

Any ideas on the syntax to do this?

Comment: Make the values returned by each case an integer instead of a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   CASE 
        WHEN c.salary = pair.salary THEN 6 :: integer
        WHEN c.salary-pair.salary <= 25000 THEN 5
        WHEN c.salary-pair.salary <= 50000 THEN 4
        WHEN c.salary-pair.salary <= 75000 THEN 3
        WHEN c.salary-pair.salary <= 100000 THEN 2
    ELSE 1
    END AS "salary_deviation"
```

Comment: `6 :: integer` is the same as `6`